# How to filter the output- Junos Automation with Ansible

Tags: ansible, junos-automation

**Purpose of my Code is to filter a specific Routing instance name from Configuration.**

My search is for a Routing Instance which is in configuration-> Routing -Instances->Instance -> name -> MY RI  and all the  lines which has MY RI
I am okay with Filter and passing kwargs but I am facing issue.

**Code:**

```
---
- name: Get RI
  hosts: junos Host
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - Juniper.junos
  tasks:
    - name: send rpc with args
      juniper_junos_rpc:
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        user: "user"
        passwd: "pssword!"
        rpc: get-config
        logfile: 'rpc.log'
        format: xml
        dest: "{{ inventory_hostname }}.xml"
        kwargs:
          filter_xml: configuration/routing-instances/instance/name = CSP-RI-L2-cc6abb1d-63ab-483f-b4ce-f4b978c877cc

**ERROR**
error:fatal: [sit-entce.tlab.equinix.com]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py:141: FutureWarning: CTR mode needs counter parameter, not IV\n  self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_T0LCbD/ansible_module_juniper_junos_rpc.py\", line 622, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_T0LCbD/ansible_module_juniper_junos_rpc.py\", line 518, in main\n    options=attr, **kwarg)\nTypeError: get_config() got multiple values for keyword argument 'filter_xml'\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
    "rc": 1
```

Any suggestions. Multiple RI would be there and I have to search one RI and print it or store all the lines which has that RI name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say a device got below configuration

```
# show | compare | display xml 
   <rpc-reply xmlns:junos="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/18.1I0/junos">
      <configuration>
            <routing-instances operation="create">
                <instance>
                    <name>pqr</name>
                    <interface>
                        <name>ge-0/0/2.0</name>
                    </interface>
                </instance>
                <instance>
                    <name>xyz</name>
                    <interface>
                        <name>ge-0/0/1.0</name>
                    </interface>
                </instance>
            </routing-instances>
    </configuration>
```

Now if you want to filter a very specific instance, you can use filter option.
filter can be used as

```
filter_xml: <routing-instances><instance><name>pqr</name></instance></routing-instances>
```

Comment: FutureWarning: CTR mode needs counter parameter, not IV\n  self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_Umx2t9/ansible_module_juniper_junos_rpc.py\", line 622, in <module>\n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_Umx2t9/ansible_module_juniper_junos_rpc.py\", line 518, in main\n    options=attr, **kwarg)\nTypeError: get_config() got multiple values for keyword argument 'filter_xml'\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
    "rc": 1

Comment: but  as you suggested we used the junos_config and not junos_rpc.